# Grails: JSON views with namespacing convention?

Tags: json, grails

Typical non-json template rendering uses naming convention to locate views, but I cannot get this to work with JSON Views.

**Sample class**

```
class StrainsController extends ManagerController {
    static namespace = "manager";

    def edit() {
        def model = []
        respond([view: "/manager/strains/edit"], model)
    }
}
```

**Folder Structure**

```
grails-app
  views
    manager
      strains
        edit.gson
```

Ideally I shouldn't have to explicitly define where my gson view is located, Grails convention over configuration motto should already handle it.  Is there a special configuration option I need to enable for this to work?

Grails 3.2.8

JSON Views 1.2.3

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a special configuration option I need to enable for this to
>   work?

No.  I expect support for that just isn't implemented.  If you file an issue at https://github.com/grails/grails-views/issues we will take a look.

Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was my fault.  When I use `respond` I need to add `static responseFormats = ['json']` to my controller in order to allow for convention mapping.

```
class StrainsController extends ManagerController {
    static namespace = "manager";
    static responseFormats = ['json'];

    def edit() {
        def model = []
        respond(model)
    }
}
```